# How to keep the data fetched on the previous page when the params are changed? (nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When I move from "/about/1" to "/about/2", I want to show the data received from "/about/1" and "/about/2" in "/about/2"

But `[/about/:page]this.$route.params.page` changes, the component is also remounted.

The data array that contained the data received in "/about/1" is initialized and becomes an empty array in "/about/2".

How do I keep the data from "/about/1" to "/about/2"?

cf.I should use `async setup() & useAsyncData`

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="(d, i) in showingData" :key="i">
    <span>{d.title}</span>
    <span>{d.description}</span>
  </div>
  <button @click="more">More</button>
</template>
```

```js
export default defineNuxtComponent({
  async setup() {
    const route = useRoute()
    const { data, refresh } =
      await useAsyncData(() => {
        return $fetch('url', {
          params: {
            page: route.params.page // 1 --> 2
          },
          method: 'get',
        })
      }, {
        initialCache: false,
        watch: [route]
      })
    ])

    return {
      data,
      refresh
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      total: [], // when more button is clicked, it becomes empty...T.T
      page: 1
    }
  },
  computed: {
    showingData() {
      if (!this.total.length) {
        this.total = this.data
      } else {
        this.total = this.total.concat(this.data)
      }

      return this.total
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // when more button is clicked, newly fetched data should be added to existing 'this.total'
    more() {
      this.$router.push({
        params: {
          page: this.page++
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `useAsyncData` at the same time.

```js
const { data, refresh } =
    await useAsyncData(() => {
        return $fetch('url', {
            params: {
                page: route.params.page // 1 --> 2
            },
            method: 'get',
        })
    }, {
        initialCache: false,
        watch: [route]
    })
])
// Page - 1
const { data: prevData, refresh: prevRefresh } =
    await useAsyncData(() => {
        return $fetch('url', {
            params: {
                page: route.params.page - 1
            },
            method: 'get',
        })
    }, {
        initialCache: false,
        watch: [route]
    })
])

return {
  data,
  refresh,
  prevData,
  prevRefresh
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, I should to show the data (/1 + /2) in /about/2. Also, data (1/ + /2 + /3) in /about/3. ... Is There any another way?

Comment: Add another asyncData and sum it like page + 1.